# jenkins scalable-amazon-ecs scale from zero

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, plugins, amazon-ecs

In Jenkins there are two similar plugins available:

[image]

Both are linked to the same [Jenkins wiki page](http://wiki%20page)

I haven't found any documentation for the scalable version of the plugin and I have the following question:

**Is it possible to add ECS instances in cluster from 0(none) to 1 using this plugin?
I want to have active ECS instances only when there are jobs to be done.**

I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround to scale out the number of ECS instances from zero.
I created a new job with the following shell code:

```
result=$(aws ecs list-container-instances --cluster ${cluster-name} | grep -c arn:aws:ecs:${aws-region}) || true
if [ "$result" = '0' ]
    then aws autoscaling set-desired-capacity --auto-scaling-group-name ${asg-name} --desired-capacity 1
else 
    echo "Container already exists"
fi
```

*replace variables* `${cluster-name}, ${aws-region}, ${asg-name}` *with actual values*

This job increases the number of ECS VMs to 1 if it was 0.

Scaling in can be done using Cloudwatch alarm and Autoscaling policy.

Comment: I don't see how adding a job to make a configuration change really addresses anything.  You could just edit the auto-scaling properties set the desired capacity to "1".  However, that doesn't address the primary concern: how can you have your Jenkins jobs run in ECS containers but have it auto-scale to 0 instances when there are no jobs pending?

Comment: @DouglasManley If you edit the desired capacity to "1" you will end up in the situation when the ECS instance lives forever.

I wanted to have running instances only when some job is running to save costs

Comment: So are you saying that *every* job has this scale-up-to-one code the beginning?

Answer (score 1):

Try to uninstall these plugins and compile ecs-slave plugin manually from the branch autoscaling https://github.com/cbamelis/amazon-ecs-plugin